# How to change mounting point?

Tags: mount, plex

By some reason Plex Media Manager won't recognize my partition(/media/radibg2/Radi/). I've tried to start

```
x-www-browser http://localhost:32400/manage
```

(this is what the plex shortcut which is showing in the search runs) as sudo but it again didn't find the files? It loads the partition empty. In the Plex forum answered me to change the mounting point to /media/Radi and it will load the files, so how to do?

Answer (score 10):

Firstly get to know the partition reference. Run `sudo blkid` and note the UUID of the partition.

Next you need to modify your `/etc/fstab` file to point to the desired mount point. Run `sudo xdg-open /etc/fstab` and add a line or modify the line referencing the partition.

An example line:

```
UUID="xxxx-xxxx"    /media/Radi ext4    defaults,user,auto  0   1
```

Then reboot your computer or run `sudo mount -a`

Answer (score 2):

Copy all the files and folders from "/media/radibg2/Radi/" to "/media/Radi".

Then unmount your partition

Example:

```
umount [EXT] /media/radibg2/Radi/
```

Edit your fstab file:

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

Change the mount point to "/media/Radi" from "/media/radibg2/Radi/" in fstab file and save the file

Now remount your partition with the mount point "/media/Radi"

Example:

```
mount -t xfs /dev/sdb1 /media/Radi
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you're changing the mount point, why first copy all the files from the mounted /media/radibg2/Radi to the unmounted (empty) directory /media/Radi? The files will stay put on whatever partition is being mounted

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see & read/view the media files at all? And `x-www-browser` is just a link to a regular web browser (firefox here), but apparently that needs Avahi to be working. And the help webpage below says the link may really be `http://localhost:32400/manage/index.html` It should work from any connected computer too (replacing localhost with the computer's ip). But running your web browser with sudo shouldn't affect the results.

After browsing https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/26727-how-to-plex-media-server-on-ubuntu/ it appears that Plex runs as it's own user, so maybe the plex user doesn't have read permission on the media files...

If you want to quickly and temporarily add a second mount point (to test if plex will see the media files mounted somewhere else) you can bind mount it to another directory with `mount --bind olddir newdir` (kind of like "linking" the two directories)

Then to change the mount point permanently just edit it's line in `/etc/fstab` changing the old /media/radibg2/Radi/ into /media/Radi (FYI `lsblk` will tell you what partition is currently mounted where).