# How do I mount external drive to the same mountpoint every time?

Tags: usb, mount, xubuntu, hard-drive

I'm having this issue under Xubuntu 21.10 (kernel 5.11.0-41-generic).

When clicking on a USB external drive label in Thunar's sidebar after I've plugged it in (so it shows up but is still unmounted), the drive mounts with a different *"label"* each time. It's always mounted in the same parent folder, but the folder it's mounted to is `/media/$USER/DRIVE_NAME$NUMBER`, where **$NUMBER** is a number that increments each time I mount the drive.

How do I mount the drive to the same mountpoint each time it's plugged in?

Comment: Unplug the drive, then remove all remaining /medis/$USER/drive_name* directories. Perhaps then reboot. That could solve the issue, where the system can normally recreate the default mount point again, and remove it when the drive is disconnected.

Comment: Your problem does not occur for me in a persistent live Xubuntu 21.10; 1. *Please describe your system with more details, for example how you have modified it;* 2. Also, in order to know details about your computer, please [download and run the `system-info` script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/). Let it upload the result to a pastebin and paste the link into a new comment here. It will make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the mount point in `/etc/fstab`.
So you would set the name, and your partition would always mount with the same name.
The header of the file is reasonably explanatory

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
```

see [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/555289/226614):

1. Run a combination of `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo blkid` to identify the UUID of your partition.
2. Edit with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` (or use the editor of your choice).
3. Add a line like `UUID="xxxx-xxxx"    /media/<mount point of your choice> ext4    defaults,user,auto  0   1`.
4. Reboot.

The exact flags to use should be fine tuned.
You have to create directory `/media/<mount point of your choice>` for the mount to take place.

Comment: @nobody - Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I use to mount automatically an USB drive:

#### 1. Create mount point

```
$ sudo mkdir /mount/<usb-drive-name>
```

`<usb-drive-name>` [name it how you like](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Fstab_File_Configuration), but please keep in mind that

> Mount points should not have spaces in the names.

#### 2. Find out the `UUID` and `TYPE` of your drive

```
$ sudo blkid
```

will give you a list of mounted drives, find your USB drive:

```
...
/dev/sda1: LABEL="my-usb-drive" UUID="e6a1db23-be63-4b39-b263-e68101bb179d" TYPE="ext4"
...
```

#### 3. Edit `fstab`

(I use `vim`, but any editor is good)

```
$ sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

Usually it looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# These are the filesystems that are always mounted on boot, you can
# override any of these by copying the appropriate line from this file into
# /etc/fstab and tweaking it as you see fit.  See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump> <pass>
/dev/root       /              ext4    defaults        0 1
/swfile         none           swap    sw              0 0
```

Add this line if `TYPE` is `ext4` (linux partition):

```
# <file system> <mount point>             <type>          <options>                               <dump> <pass>
/dev/root            /                     ext4           defaults                                     0 1
/swfile              none                  swap           sw                                           0 0
UUID="e6a1db23-be63-4b39-b263-e68101bb179d" /media/<usb-drive-name> ext4 defaults                      0 2
```

Add this line if `TYPE` is `ntfs` (windows partition):

```
# <file system> <mount point>             <type>          <options>                               <dump> <pass>
/dev/root            /                     ext4           defaults                                     0 1
/swfile              none                  swap           sw                                           0 0
UUID="e6a1db23-be63-4b39-b263-e68101bb179d" /media/<usb-drive-name> ntfs defaults                      0 0
```

Add this line if `TYPE` is `fat` (*all OS* partition):

```
# <file system> <mount point>             <type>          <options>                               <dump> <pass>
/dev/root            /                     ext4           defaults                                     0 1
/swfile              none                  swap           sw                                           0 0
UUID="e6a1db23-be63-4b39-b263-e68101bb179d" /media/<usb-drive-name> fat defaults                       0 0
```

The PASS (fsck order param) explanation:

> In practice, use "1" for your root partition / and 2 for the rest. All partitions marked with a "2" are checked in sequence and you do not need to specify an order.

> For the `pass` param, use "0" to disable checking the file system at boot or for network shares.

Here are the [fstab options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Options) explained.

#### 4. (optional) Add USB drive to your home directory

If you want that mounted usb drive to appear also automatically in your `HOME` directory, add this line to `fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>             <type>          <options>                               <dump> <pass>
/dev/root            /                     ext4           defaults                                     0 1
/swfile              none                  swap           sw                                           0 0
UUID="e6a1db23-be63-4b39-b263-e68101bb179d" /media/<usb-drive-name> ext4 defaults                      0 2
/media/<usb-drive-name>  /home/<USERNAME>/<usb-drive-name>  none  bind                                 0 0
```